# How do you grant permission to a child account for SAML provider of other account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-access-policy, aws-iam-policy

I will start by stating that I have no experience configuring cross account permissions.(trying to remedy that)  I have set up a multi account infrastructure in AWS. I have a root account that has the SAML provider and it successfully allows me to connect to other child accounts.  I have some CDK stacks setup in the child application accounts(dev, staging, production).  When I try to deploy, I get an error stating that I don't have access to the SAML provider, which makes sense as the deployment is running against the dev account.  Here is the relevant part of the stack in question...

```js
const samlProvider = iam.SamlProvider.fromSamlProviderArn(this, "saml-provider", "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXX");
    const endpoint = this.vpc.addClientVpnEndpoint('Endpoint', {
      cidr: '10.10.0.0/16',
      serverCertificateArn: this.domainCert.certificateArn,
      userBasedAuthentication: ec2.ClientVpnUserBasedAuthentication.federated(samlProvider),
      authorizeAllUsersToVpcCidr: true,
    });
```

I believe I need to add an inline policy on the root account granting get access to the SAML provider, but I am not sure of the syntax.  Any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

I was not sure what actions were needed so I just added all of the get permissions

I tried the following policy...

```json
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GetSamlProvider",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetSAMLProvider"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I still get the same permissions error
You do not have access to supplied SAML Provider arn.

Answer (score 0):

After a few interactions with AWS support, I realized that I am going about this all wrong.  you can't use a saml provider from a separate account from the VPN endpoint.  Instead, what should be done is to set up the VPN endpoint in the same account as the saml provider then setup VPC peering so that you can access the child account VPC from the main account.